# How do I determine the number of dimensions an array has in c

Tags: arrays, c

So I want to create some functions that take arrays as input, but I don't know how many dimensions the array will have.

Is there a way in c to determine how many dimensions an array has? (ideally as a function)

Comment: no, that's not possible. You're not even going to create a function prototype that accepts arrays without knowing the dimension. Implement your own data structure

Comment: What would be a usecase for such a function? You, as the programmer, are supposed to know the type of a parameter being passed to a function.

Comment: "some functions that take arrays as input" --> Arrays cannot be received by the function as an array.  The usual alternative is to pass a pointer to the data.

Comment: Parse the input data twice: once to find out how many dimensions and their sizes, and again to read the data after allocating memory.

Answer (score 1):

So this is actually a fairly difficult problem in C. Usually this is solved using one of three ways:

1. Have a special terminating value, like `'\0'` for strings
2. Pass the dimensions of the array as a parameter to whatever function you're using
3. Keep the pointer of the array and its dimension in a `struct` together

If I remember correctly, there's a way to figure out the size of an allocated array using *nix systems, but I definitely would **not** recommend doing this. Just keep track of your allocated memory.

Comment: Yeah you can figure out the size of the array in some situations, but not its dimensions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10349610/15801843